# Store output from arp -g into powershell variable

Tags: powershell, variables, arp

I need store only MAC address information (Physical Address)

```
arp -g 10.205.128.115 
output: 
Interface: 10.205.128.101 --- 0xb
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.205.128.115        48-2a-e3-28-b0-f5     dynamic
```

I need only 48-2a-e3-28-b0-f5

this is closest to what I need but I believe that there is simplest way:

```
$macarray = @()
arp -g 10.205.128.115 | Foreach{ 

        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        #IP  = ($_ -split "\s+")[1]
        MAC = ($_ -split "\s+")[2]
        }
IF (!($obj.MAC -eq "---" -or $obj.MAC -eq "Address" -or $obj.MAC -eq $null -or $obj.MAC -eq "ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff")) {$macarray += $obj}
}
$macarray






$macarray = @()
arp -g 10.205.128.115 | Foreach{ 

        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        #IP  = ($_ -split "\s+")[1]
        MAC = ($_ -split "\s+")[2]
        }
IF (!($obj.MAC -eq "---" -or $obj.MAC -eq "Address" -or $obj.MAC -eq $null -or $obj.MAC -eq "ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff")) {$macarray += $obj}
}
$macarray
```

Answer (score 0):

This works! But I think this solution is "to robust"

```
$macarray = @()
arp -g 10.205.128.115 | foreach {

    ($_ -split "\s+")[2]} | Where-Object -FilterScript { -Not ($_ -eq "---" -or $_ -eq "Address" -or $_ -eq $null -or $_ -eq "ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff")} 

#foreach {$i.Add($_)} $i

$macarray
```

Comment: is this intended to get the MAC for a computer on your network? if so, you may be able to use `Get-CimInstance` to grab the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off using `Get-CimInstance` or `Get-WmiObject` as [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggested than trying to parse the output from the arp command:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
    Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -match '\S+' } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Internet Address'; Expression = {$_.IPAddress[0]}}, 
                  @{Name = 'Physical Address'; Expression = {$_.MACAddress}}, 
                  @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = {if ($_.DHCPEnabled) {'dynamic'} else {'static'}}}, 
                  Description
```

The output of the above will be something like:

> ```
> Internet Address Physical Address  Type    Description                                                         
> ---------------- ----------------  ----    -----------                                                         
> 192.168.0.14     00:24:1D:C7:38:64 dynamic Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
> 192.168.56.1     0A:00:27:00:00:0F static  VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
> ```

Comment: For remote Win10 computers with LAPS is simpliest solution ARP. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

- You can better parse arp output with a RegEx,
- Windows 8+ / Windows Server 2012+ have the `Get-NetNeighbor` cmdlet

---

```
$IP = '10.205.128.115'

# to parse arp output
$MAC= (arp -g $IP | Select-String -Pattern '(([0-9a-f]){2}-){5}([0-9a-f]){2}').Matches.Value
$MAC

# a more owerShell like approach 
$MAC = (Get-NetNeighbor $IP).LinkLayerAddress
$Mac
```